# Regex for a recursive grammar in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, grammar, xregexp

Suppose I have the following fictional grammar, with a recursive definition for clause.

```
sentence := clause +
subject := (qualifier *) subjectiveNoun
objects := object +
object := nothing | (qualifier *) objectiveNoun
clause := subject objects verb
qualifier := adjective | clause
```

Assuming everything else has a non recursive definition, how should can approach writing a javascript grammar for 'clause'? If someone is familiar with the XRegExp library to do this, that would be an added plus.

Comment: Before people start yelling *"regular expressions ... cannot match nested/recursive ..."*: The XRegExp library *does* support recursive matching: http://xregexp.com/plugins/#matchRecursive @wasabiwimp, [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and what is your goal here? If you're able to match this with regex, then what? If you're planning to process the parse tree, then regex is of little use, this will only tell you the source matched or not. In that case, have a look into [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) or [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/).

Comment: Can you pick out the `subjectiveNoun` and `objectiveNoun` and `verb` unambiguously?

Comment: What kind of grammar is this?  I'm confused by "write a javascript grammar for 'clause'" since you already have a grammar.  Might you mean "write a javascript parser"?

Comment: Isn't `objects` deeply ambiguous since it can match any number of runs of `nothing`?  Wouldn't `object := (qualifier *) objectiveNoun; objects := object*` be less ambiguous.

Comment: @Mike Samuel I intended this as a simple example, and wasn't intended to be a natural language grammar. All of the rules that I didn't define here were supposed to be easily resolvable. I just wanted to highlight the recursive portion of the grammar and learn how to deal with that.

Comment: @BartKiers can you repost that as an answer so I can accept it? It is indeed parsing that I wanted to do, PEG.js will handle some recursive cases, and overall looks like it will fit the bill...

Comment: @wasabiwimp, okay, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XRegExp library *does* support recursive matching<sup>1</sup>, but what is your goal here? If you're able to match this with regex, then what? If you're planning to process the parse tree, then regex is of little use, this will only tell you the source matched or not. In that case, have a look into [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) or [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/).

<sup>1</sup> http://xregexp.com/plugins/#matchRecursive

Answer (score 0):

[Ometa](http://tinlizzie.org/ometa/) makes it easy to write parsers in JS for analytic grammars and does some tricks to handle LR which means it should be able to handle your grammar, but PEG grammars are rarely used for natural language parsing.